# Oracle provider for .NET 4

Tags: oracle, .net-4.0, provider

HI,

I'm developing a website on ASP.NET. The database is Oracle 10 g. When I deploy the website I get an exception message "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.".The environment is Visual Studio 2010.I downloaded and installed ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) but I still get the exception.I'd also installed Oracle client 10 g.But it failed too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. I could fix this problem by installing a patch provided by Oracle. If one uses typed Datasets they shoud install the patch as well after installing the ODP itself.Thanks whoever tried to answer.